# NSString *latestVersionString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am currently using this in my Xcode 5 application and I can't seem to get it working

```
NSString *bundleVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];

NSString *latestVersionString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com/version.txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

#import NSString+compareToVersion.h

if ([bundleVersion isOlderThanVersion:latestVersionString]) {
// show a blocking modal view, with a button to link to the app store}
```

Comment: I am using this to restrict the user from playing the game when there is an update out and forcing them to update to the latest version

Comment: what is the error/output and what do you expect from it

Comment: When there is an update on the appstore, and you open the app it should make a popup saying go update on the appstore and won't let them play until they update

Comment: As of right now it's doing nothing and isn't working

Comment: Add the following: `NSLog(@"latestVersionString = \"%@\"", latestVersionString);`. Update your question with the output of that line.

Comment: Do i add that to my appdelegate.m?

Comment: Please please please use an asynchronous connection to the remote .txt file.

Comment: Should i be putting that code in my appdelegate.m? Do i need to include any frameworks?

Comment: Please see my answer below to help you

Comment: @user136882 Add the `NSLog` statement I mentioned to the code you posted in the question, where ever that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I do not recommend using synchronous network calls, regardless of how small the .txt file may be. You can try this for your code: Make sure to include `<UIAlertViewDelegate>` in your .h file first.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com/version.txt"]];
    request.timeoutInterval = 10.0;
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:
     ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         if (data)
         {
             NSString *bundleVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
             NSString *latestVersionString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

             if (![bundleVersion isEqualToString:latestVersionString])
             {
                 // The two strings are not equal, dispatch to the UI thread and show a UIAlertView

                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                 {
                     UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Update App!"
                     message:@"Please download the newer version available first on the App Store!"
                     delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"App Store"
                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
                     [alertView show];

                     [[UIApplication sharedApplication]endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
                  });
             }
             else
             {
                 // Up to date; no new version is available, proceed to game play routines
                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
             }
         }
         else
         {
             // No internet, or there is no data at the url, show error
             // Uncomment below line if you want the user to interact with app again
             // [[UIApplication sharedApplication]endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
         }
     }];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your App Store app link here"]];
}
```

Comment: And i place this file in my AppDelegate.m?

Comment: Do you not use view controllers?

Comment: Yes i use viewcontrollers

Comment: Place it where you need to check for the current version before game play commences. Call: `[self checkForNewerVersion];`

Comment: I want it to check on startup and if there is a new version they will not be able to play app until they update

Comment: Put it whereever the first code in your app gets executed before your game play routines..

Comment: Ok but the code you gave me is for an alert view i want the app to be disabled and not playable unless they update yours is just an alert they can dismiss

Comment: Can you not figure out how to restrict your own game play code? Also, no, it goes to the App Store.

Comment: I do not know much about objective c or any programming language

Comment: Putting it in the app delegate is better that way every time the app becomes active you can check again and display alert

Comment: Ok i understand that but an alert view is not going to stop a user from playing the app they can just dismiss that

Comment: It dismisses and goes to the App Store.. and if they come back without updating, you show alert again making it annoying to them. You can also disable all touch events in your app

Comment: How do i disable touch events

Comment: And my version.txt should just include lets say.           1.0.2      And thats it right?

Comment: Should try to test it now, should drop right in and be easy to test. You should format the .txt string to look like the `CFBundleShortVersionString` So if that is 1.0, then make it 1.01 in your .txt with no whitespace or blank new lines!

Comment: So if my app version was 1.0.3 i would make the text completely blank with one line containing this? 1.02

Comment: Yes. The .txt would have 4 characters in that case

Comment: I have one more question, how can i make it so it fetches the latest version on the appstore so i don't have to upload a new txt file every time?

Comment: You can't, you'll have to use a 3rd party website like AppAnnie and grab the value from their HTML file using scraping. Problem here is those websites takes hours and sometimes days to auto refresh

Comment: Ok now my viewcontrollers started bugging a lot is that a result of the restriction to update?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem

Comment: In my viewcontroller i have a moving title and image that go up and back down. After doing this update restriction when the app loads it goes up and than doesn't come down and eventually goes off the screen

Comment: Has nothing to do with it

Comment: Could you help me with that too?

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication]beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];          I have a gamecenter alert when players are not signed in and whenever you click dismiss this is not letting users touch

Comment: Call: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]endIgnoringInteractionEvents];`

Comment: But that will alow users to touch after my update restriction

Comment: You'll have to come up with your own logic. Just call: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];` again when you don't want touches!

Answer (score 0):

First, check the value of `latestVersionString` in the debugger. Make sure it is the value you want it to be (and not e.g. `nil`). Also, declare an `NSError *` to capture any error that arises from trying to initialise a string from an HTTP URL (consider the case where there may be no internet connection, or temporary routing or DNS issue etc.).

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *latestVersionString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com/version.txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if (error != nil)
{
    // figure out what went wrong based on the error
}
else
{
    // check latestVersionString contains something valid and then compare
    // with bundleVersion.
}
```

If both `bundleVersion` and `latestVersionString` contain what you expect, then the issue may be in the `isOlderThanVersion:` method.